# Android NDK failing to allocate large amount of memory

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have NDK app that needs to allocate large amount of memory (50MB) but unfortunately malloc() returns null and errno is set to 12 indicates ENOMEM.

However just before I start my application I do see that 'Device Memory' shows I have 1.7GB memory free. Also heapsize/heapmaxfree shouldn't be in picture when allocating memory from 'C' application I have attached that info below.

```
[dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit]: [128m]
[dalvik.vm.heapmaxfree]: [8m]
[dalvik.vm.heapminfree]: [2m]
[dalvik.vm.heapsize]: [512m]
[dalvik.vm.heapstartsize]: [8m]
[dalvik.vm.heaptargetutilization]: [0.75]
```

What could be the reason why I am unable to allocate large amount of memory using malloc() from my NDK code?

Also I have used the ActivityManager API to retrieve memory class and avaialble memory and it shows following output and my manifest request includes android:largeHeap="true"

```
onCreate GetMemoryClass => 128
onCreate getLargeMemoryClass => 512
onCreate avmem => 456 MB

MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long avmem = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
Log.d(mTAG, "onCreate GetMemoryClass => " + am.getMemoryClass() );
Log.d(mTAG, "onCreate getLargeMemoryClass => " + am.getLargeMemoryClass() );
Log.d(mTAG, "onCreate avmem => " + avmem + " MB");
```

So it continues to puzzle me why there is 450MB memory available and malloc() is not able to allocate 50MB memory is it something broken on part of memory management or that is how things are supposed to be?

I am running my program on Android 4.4.1 on Galaxy S4 device.

Comment: Your 1.7GB of "free" memory probably is not truly free, but rather is made up mostly of cached processes that can be terminated to free up memory. I presume that there is a technique for making large allocations like this from the NDK, though I don't do much NDK work and therefore do not know the details.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my question, and verified that plenty of memory available per the Android's activity manager. I wonder if this is issue because of way dalvik does garbage collection/memory management?

Comment: The memory class and large memory class represent your Dalvik heap limit and have no relevance here. And quoting [the documentation for `availMem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.html#availMem): "This number should not be considered absolute: due to the nature of the kernel, a significant portion of this memory is actually in use and needed for the overall system to run well. "

Comment: There is some chance that your `malloc()` call is wrong. Let us try few simple steps to verify this. Try to malloc 1 Megabyte instead of 50. Does this work? Try to malloc your memory from [`Application.onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()). Does this work?

Comment: Adding to Alex Cohn's comment: if 1 Meg works try allocating it 50 times to get your 50 Meg. The heap may be fragmented and a single block of 50 Meg may not be available.

Comment: Well I wrote a small app that just attempts to map 1KB ( 1024 bytes) incrementally. All I was able to allocate was 13KB of data!